# Linear Regression over time series with multiple outputs

Tags: python, pandas, regression, linear-regression

I've been working with U.S. NOAA's (National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration) Global Mean Sea Level dataset. There are 4 satellites provide information, so, there are 4 columns and year column. Those satellites provided informations within a specific time interval. For example; satellite Posedion worked within 1992-2006, Jason-1 worked within 2003-2014 etc. Of course, there will be lots of NaN values where Jason-1 doesn't serve but Poseidon does.

What I want is to plot linear line to calculate sea level rise, that's all. I want those four columns to be fit with year column. Couldn't cracked yet..

```
Here is my code;

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
from sklearn import linear_model
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pylab
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

Atlantic = pd.read_csv('C:\\Atlantic_Free2.csv', error_bad_lines=False)

Atlantic = Atlantic[~np.isnan(Atlantic)]

Poseidon = Atlantic['Poseidon']
Jason1 = Atlantic['Jason1']
Jason2 = Atlantic['Jason2']
Jason3 = Atlantic['Jason3']


plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))

colors = ["blue", "red", "green", "purple"]
texts = ["Poseidon", "Jason1", "Jason2", "Jason3"]
patches = [ plt.plot([],[], marker="o", ms=10, ls="", mec=None, color=colors[i], 
            label="{:s}".format(texts[i]) )[0]  for i in range(len(texts)) ]
plt.legend(handles=patches, loc='upper left', ncol=1, facecolor="grey", numpoints=1 )


plt.plot(Atlantic, Poseidon , 'ro', color='blue')

plt.plot(Atlantic, Jason1 , 'ro', color='red')

plt.plot(Atlantic, Jason2 , 'ro', color='green')

plt.plot(Atlantic, Jason3 , 'ro', color='purple')




plt.ylabel('Change in mean sea level [mm]', fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('Years', fontsize=20)
plt.title('Atlantic Ocean - Mean Sea Level', fontsize=20)

plt.axis([1992, 2018, -25, 80])

plt.grid(True)
plt.plot()
plt.show()
```

Output of the code above, added to below.

[image]

Comment: Include attempted code

Comment: If you are asking about regression methodology, this question is better suited to the Data Science Stack Exchange.